# QMenu テキストやアイコンではなく、ウィジェット自体で表示したい

Tags: qt, pyside, pyqt

QMenuで、QActionを表示したいのですが、
テキストやアイコンではなく、ウィジェットそれ自体をアクションとして
扱いたいです。例えば、Wordなどでいえば、アンダーラインスタイルを
変更するのに、ダッシュラインや、ドットラインなどのテキストによる
指示ではなく、____________ や、_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _等の図が、メニューに
現れるようにしたいのですが、どなたか方法をご存知ありませんか？
下に現在トライ中のコードを置きました。メニューは押すと、ごみ粕みたいな
ウィジェットらしきものが出ます。`resize`などで元のウィジェットのサイズを
かえようとしても、変わりません。paintEvent内は冗長なコードになっていますが
ご容赦ください。

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

import sys



class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar()

        self.a_menu = QtGui.QMenu("a-menu")
        self.a_menu.resize(500,10)

        self.label_A = UnderlineStyleLabel(self.a_menu,QtGui.QTextCharFormat.WaveUnderline)
        self.label_A.resize(500,10)
        self.widgetAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.a_menu)
#        self.widgetAction.setText("DashDotDotLine")
        self.widgetAction.createWidget(self.label_A)
        self.widgetAction.setDefaultWidget(self.label_A)
        self.widgetAction.setEnabled(True)
        self.connect(self.widgetAction,QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.print_)
        self.a_menu.addAction(self.widgetAction)

        self.menubar.addMenu(self.a_menu)

        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.show()

    def print_(self):
        print("A")
class UnderlineStyleLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,underlineStyle=QtGui.QTextCharFormat.NoUnderline):
        super(UnderlineStyleLabel,self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.pen_linepath = QtGui.QPainterPath(QtCore.QPointF(0,0))        
        self.pen_linepath.lineTo(100,0)
        self.resize(100,100)
        self.underlineStyle = underlineStyle

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        if self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.NoUnderline:
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.NoPen)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)        
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)     
            painter.setPen(pen)
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawPath(self.pen_linepath)     
            painter.end()
        elif self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.SingleUnderline:
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)        
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)     
            painter.setPen(pen)
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawPath(self.pen_linepath)     
            painter.end()
        elif self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.DashUnderline:
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.DashLine)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)        
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)     
            painter.setPen(pen)
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawPath(self.pen_linepath)     
            painter.end()
        elif self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.DotLine:
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.DotLine)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)        
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)     
            painter.setPen(pen)
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawPath(self.pen_linepath)     
            painter.end()
        elif self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.DashDotLine:
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.DashDotLine)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)        
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)     
            painter.setPen(pen)
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawPath(self.pen_linepath)     
            painter.end()
        elif self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.DashDotDotLine:
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.DashDotDotLine)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)        
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)     
            painter.setPen(pen)
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawPath(self.pen_linepath)     
            painter.end()
        #Wavelineを出したい。
        elif self.underlineStyle == QtGui.QTextCharFormat.WaveUnderline:
            pen = QtGui.QPen()
            pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine)
            pen.setWidth(10)
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter()
            if not painter.isActive():
                painter.begin(self)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
            painter.drawArc(10,10,10,10,480,1920)
            painter.drawArc(20,7,10,10,-480,-1920)
            painter.drawArc(30,10,10,10,480,1920)
            painter.drawArc(40,7,10,10,-480,-1920)
            painter.drawArc(50,10,10,10,480,1920)
            painter.drawArc(60,7,10,10,-480,-1920)
            painter.end()
        return QtGui.QWidget.paintEvent(self,event)
def main():

    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(18,e)
    w = Window()



    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QWidgetAction`の使い方はあっていると思います。
「`UnderlineStyleLabel`」の`sizeHint`メソッドを再定義(override)して、表示させたいサイズを返すようにすれば、描画したものが見えるようになると思います。

＃`sizeHint`メソッドは`QWidget`クラスのメソッドです。
  (`QWidget.sizeHint()`は"invalid size"を返すため、このような動作になると予想します)